# how check the given date day in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check if  given date is friday or not. if so, need to modify the date to sunday.

> for example 03-FEB-23 is friday, so need to change the bus_date to sunday.

```
define cu_date='03-FEB-23'
expected output bus_dat=05-FEB-23
```

Comment: Do you want just Fridays to become Sundays? What about Thursdays and Saturdays?

Comment: yeah, just friday to sunday..

Answer (score 2):

To find Sunday of any given date's week, you can use the `NEXT_DAY` function (subtracting 1 from the day so that if it is already Sunday then you get the current week's value rather than the next week's):

```sql
DECLARE
  cu_date  DATE := DATE '2023-02-03';
  bus_date DATE := NEXT_DAY(cu_date-1, 'SUNDAY');
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bus_date);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 2023-02-05 00:00:00
> ```

Or, to do it independently of the NLS date language settings, you can compare to the start of the ISO week:

```sql
DECLARE
  cu_date  DATE := DATE '2023-02-03';
  bus_date DATE := cu_date + 6 - (TRUNC(cu_date) - TRUNC(cu_date, 'IW'));
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bus_date);
END;
/
```

Which has the same output.

---

If you only want to set the value when it is a Friday then you can use a `CASE` expression to check the day of the week and then add 2 days:

```sql
DECLARE
  cu_date  DATE := DATE '2023-02-03';
  bus_date DATE := CASE
                   WHEN TO_CHAR(cu_date, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') = 'Friday'
                   THEN cu_date + 2
                   END;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bus_date);
END;
/
```

or, independent of the NLS settings:

```sql
DECLARE
  cu_date  DATE := DATE '2023-02-03';
  bus_date DATE := CASE
                   WHEN TRUNC(cu_date) - TRUNC(cu_date, 'IW') = 4 -- Friday
                   THEN cu_date + 2
                   END;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bus_date);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fl_VtCKS)

Comment: Normally, for such things you should have in your database a business calendar table having two date columns: actual_date and business_date. Eventually, if operating in several countries, you should have several business calendars, which would be represented in two table: business_calendars - master containing the name of the calendar and ID, and business_calandar_days -detail containing calendar_id,  actual_date and business_date. That because there may be floating holidays and, eventually there may come laws for new holidays or for abolishing some holidays

Comment: @BogdanDincescu That is very dependent on the application and the business requirements. Stating that you "should" have it is too strong a statement as for many use-cases it is simply not a requirement to store that information and calculating the day-of-week on the fly is perfectly acceptable.